# How to read a text file with a mix of int and strings delimited by space and store each into arrays

Tags: java, regex, arrays, input, java.util.scanner

I have a text file with about 200 item numbers and descriptions, which is formatted like this (without the bullets):

- 1642 Pure wool t-shirt
- 613  Red laced shoes
- 3477 Blue hat with feather
- ...

I am trying to read and store the items numbers and descriptions into respective arrays, which is delimited by space. My issues are:

1. I want to ignore the spaces in the description.
2. When I sort or delete items, I want to ensure that the description gets deleted as well.

Here's what I have tried so far but getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error and I am not even sure if it will read the description properly:

```
private Scanner file;
private int item = 0;
private String desc = "";
private int[] itemArr = new int[200];
private String[] descArr = new String[200];
int n = 0;


public void openFile(){

    try{
        file = new Scanner(new File("inventory.txt"));
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

}

public void readFile(){         

    while(file.hasNextLine()){    
        if (file.hasNextInt()){     
            item = file.nextInt();
        }

        while(!file.hasNextInt() && !file.hasNextLine()){
            desc = desc + file.next() + " ";
        }

        itemArr[n] = item;
        descArr[n] = desc;
        n++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.println(itemArr[i] + " " + descArr[n] + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Total Records (n): " + n);

}
```

Or is there a better way to do this? I've read some post about Patterns and Regex, but not sure how to use that either.

Thank you!

Comment: My advice would be to refactor your input file format into something more representative, like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), if you feel using a database is inappropriate for the problem you're trying to solve. Fixed array indexing is fine for a small test case, but it's not robust enough to elegantly handle changes in your input data structures. As a bonus, JSON would handle the type identification and [deserialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for you.

Comment: "about 200 items"? If you do not know the length for sure, I would recommend using a List. Additionally, I would recommend creating an Item object to store the data, making the List store <Item>. Regex is the way to go for pulling out the individual pieces, but I'm not great with it so I can't give you a pattern

Comment: Do you have to handle items like "1234 Official 39ers Jersey"?

Comment: @Thomas: no, only characters in the description
MrGomez:thank you, but sounds beyond my puny brain capacity x(
ggrigery: I'll look into lists, thank you

Comment: @hugTears I've been trying to work out the regex pattern to no avail. I think its somewhat similar to `(\d+\D+)`. If you add the `regex` tag to your question, a regex guru may wander by and give you a hand. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no protection on `n` exceeding `200`. If there are more that 200 iterations of the `while` loop then:

```
itemArr[n] = item;
```

will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If the `int` at the beginning of each line is unique you could use a `Map<Integer, String>` to store the data. This will not place a limit of `200` on the number of items that can be read from the file and if you selected a `TreeMap` as the implementation it would sort them (you can either accept the natural ordering of `Integer` or define you own `Comparator`). As suggested by [sethu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836487/sethu) you could use a `BufferedReader` to read the file.

For example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.txt"));
Map<Integer, String> items = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

String line;
while (null != (line = br.readLine()))
{
    String[] line_parts = line.split(" ");
    if (line_parts.length > 1)
    {
        StringBuilder desc = new StringBuilder(line_parts[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < line_parts.length; i++)
        {
            desc.append(line_parts[i]);
        }
        items.put(new Integer(line_parts[0]), desc.toString());
    }
}

for (Integer key: items.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(key + " = " + items.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally do an IndexOf for the first space, then followed by a substring from 0 to the resulst of the IndexOf and a ParseInt to get the item number.

Then I would do a substring of IndexOf to end of the line, and do a Trim on the result for good measure.

In your example, you also have no protection on your Array, if you have more than 200 lines in your file, you're gonna run out of space on your array. You should use a collection like `ArrayList`

It would look something like this:

First we change the declaration of your Array for ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<Integer> itemArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<String> descArr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Second, we change your algorithm to use `SubStrings` and `IndexOf` and use `ArrayList`

```
public void readFile(){         

while(file.hasNextLine()){

     String line = file.getNextLine();
     int indexOfSpace = line.IndexOf(" ");
     int item = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,indexOfSpace));
     String description = line.substring(indexOfSpace).trim();

     itemArr.add(item);
     descArr.add(description);
     }
 }
```

If you want to go one step further, you could create a `Class` to represent your items and only have to use one `ArrayList` instead of 2, but I think I covered your question already!

Comment: thank you, but I'm getting "syntax errors in token" in the declarations of ArrayList :S

Answer (score 0):

I wont write the code but I'll give you an algorithm:

1. Use a BufferedReader to read each line of the file.
2. Split each line into a String array based on space using String.split(" ")
3. Go through each element of the String array and it to a StringBuffer until you reach a String which all numbers. There are many ways of checking if the String is all numbers. Check each character, use a regular expression and match the pattern, use the apache commons StringUtils class.
4. If you have reached a number, then you know whatever you collected in the StringBuffer is the description. The ideal data structure to use in this case, is a TreeMap. Add the description as the key and the value as the price. You can sort the map and delete entries as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this which would be much better

```
Pattern itemPatt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)\\s([a-zA-z\\s]*)");

Matcher m = itemPatt.matcher(fileStr);

if (m.matches()) {

  int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));

  String itemDescription = m.group(2);

}
```